# Does employer matching count toward the yearly 401(k) limit?

Tags: united-states, 401k, contribution, limits

The federal government limits how much I can put into a 401(k) per year.  For 2017, I think it's $18,000.  Is this just my contributions, or does it count employer matching?

Answer (score 17):

Employer contributions do not count toward the individual contribution limit, which for 2017 is, 18K.

However they do count toward the combined contribution limit, which for 2017, is 54K.

[See this link for a less timely explanation.](http://www.bankrate.com/retirement/employer-match-counts-toward-401k-limit/)